# Fabricjs accessibility options for the visually impaired

Tags: accessibility, fabricjs, color-blindness

Are there ready-made solutions or options for adapting generated/drawn images (canvas, svg) for visually impaired people in [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)? I mean, for example, accessibility options for people with color blindness. Options like "invert colors" and "high contrast", "greyscale high contrast" [are presented](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters) but as I can understood they must be applied to each element separately.

I also could not find ready-made filters adapted for people with visual impairments such as protanopia or deuteranopia.

I need such configuration options that will be applied to the entire image/canvas without the need to create and apply them manually to individual elements.